# Multipart Form Data Upload to HTTP server with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, https, multipartform-data

I have an HTTP server that supports multipart form upload of files. The working curl request looks like

```
curl  -v --location --request POST 'http://192.168.1.3:9876/storage/module' \
--form 'name="I0000000001"' \
--form 'type="Log"' \
--form 'version="1.0.0.1"' \
--form 'user="admin"' \
--form 'file=@"/tmp/logDump.tgz"'
```

But I'm not able to convert this to C# successfully. The server is throwing HTTP 500 since the parameters (`name`, `version`, `type`, and `user`) are missing when sending with C#. I'm able to make this same file upload work in Curl, Python and C++, so it is not an issue with the server, but with my C# code.

```
string filePath = @"/tmp/logDump.tgz";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs))
            {
                using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
                {
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

                    form.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("SIM00000001"), "name");
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("Log"), "type");
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("1.0.0.135"), "version");
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("admin"), "user");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.3:9876/storage/module", form);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    Console.WriteLine($" result is {response.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this correctly?

Comment: You need to tell what is the error, problem you are facing.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, getting http 500

Comment: Have you tried debugging the API code? What line is throwing the exception? Internal server error is nothing but the exception that your code is running into being translated into generic error code.

Comment: Since you are getting server side error code, if you also have the code of your webapp, debug that and see whether it is getting the payload of your POST call as expected.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran edited question after checking the error from api server.

Comment: so those params are not posted to your server. replace the lines `form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("Log"), "type");` with `form.Add(new StringContent("Log"), "type");` and try. Make this change for name, version and user params too.

Comment: With StringContent it is working, @AnandSowmithiran

Comment: Gr8, added as answer, you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multipart form data should be sent as just key-value pairs, replace the below lines,

```
 form.Add(new System.Net.Http.MultipartContent("SIM00000001"), "name");
 ...
```

to,

```
 form.Add(new StringContent("SIM00000001"), "name");
 ...
```